# How to differentiate the documents uploaded from SharePoint and CRM

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, dynamics-crm

We have integrated to SharePoint 2013 foundation with  MSCRM 2016 and the users are uploading the documents  from SharePoint portal an CRM portal to a single integrated  documents library and  was working fine as expected. I need to know how can differentiate the documents uploaded from SharePoint and CRM without adding any new metadata columns to the library. I mean can we achieve the requirement by any default columns or content type available in SharePoint.  Any suggestion for for this requirement